# I tried making a camera that only moves at certain times and it failed miserably

Tags: c#, camera

(2D)
I'm making a small prototype and tried experimenting with a camera that moves from one position to another when the player enters a trigger.
But instead it simply makes the cameras z position 0 and moves it slightly to the right.

It also gives me the error of "(8,22): warning CS0108: 'endLevel.camera' hides inherited member 'Component.camera'. Use the new keyword if hiding was intended." but I don't know how to fix this.

The script is attached to the trigger object.

```
public class endLevel : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform camera;
public Transform rightPoint;//spot camera moves towards on the right
public Transform leftPoint;//spot on the left
public float speed;
void OnTriggerEnter2D ()
{
    if(camera.position == leftPoint.position)
    {
        camera.position = Vector2.Lerp(leftPoint.position, rightPoint.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);//initially used MoveTowards and still failed
    }else if(camera.position == rightPoint.position)
    {
        camera.position = Vector2.Lerp(rightPoint.position, leftPoint.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);//initially used MoveTowards and still failed
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It means `MonoBehaviour` already has a property named camera. So adding `public Transform camera` hides it.

Your class inherits from `MonoBehaviour`, so you have access to the public properties from `Monobehaviour`

You don't have to add `public Transform camera` in your class.